# The system is runnng in low-graphics mode(Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ati, graphics

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my new HP-15-Pavillion E026ax laptop with configuration AMD A10 processor with dual radeon graphics, when I starts the Ubuntu os it always says **The system is running in low-graphics mode** and also shows in console **[drm:radeon_acpi_init] ERROR Cannot find a backlight controller**. Please help me if possible. I m fully fed up with Ubuntu now. I do all of ur solutions on askubuntu and Ubuntu forums. I also installed Ubuntu 14.04 thrice in a day... please do needful as soon as possible. sudo apt-get install fgrlx..but this command is not a solution for me...

Comment: Which driver did you install? How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Choose additional drivers tab, then see if there available drivers.

Next after choosing the available driver restart your computer.

If that didn't work, try this command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

and change the value to different driver.

Thats all i can think of.